# Android SDK DDMS in Eclipse not recognizing my Android Phone

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, device, ddms

I just purchased a ZTE Cricket X500 running 2.3.4 for the purpose of testing my Android apps on. When I start the DDMS in the Eclipse Android SDK the device is not listed. The phone is in debug mode, Unknown Sources is enabled, and as far as I can tell the neccesary USB drivers have been installed. Furthermore I have a "Android Dev Phone 1" and the DDMS is able to recognizing that. My computer is running Windows 7. Any theories as to what might be going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is because of your drivers, So install drivers for your device in your computer, then try to use it in dubug mode. so for that you have to put your device in debug-gable mode.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I uninstalled/re-installed my drivers. This time it asked me to format the hard-drive of the device and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

try these commands:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

for some reason, this works for  if the  device isn't listed

Comment: +1 Worked like a charm! Was getting "device offline" errors when launching my app all of a sudden. Tried restarting Eclipse and then the Launcher said something like "Device version: Unknown". Thought my USB cable had broke but switching didn't help. This did, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up) and done everything required?

As the link says, if you are on a Windows machine or Linux machine, you need to tell your system to recognize the vendor ID for your phone. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I have follow that tutorial. Isn't adding the Vendor ID only for Linux systems. BTW I am running Windows 7.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used a windows pc for android development, so I don't think I can really help.